# how to migrate custom printer forms from windows xp home edition win 7

Tags: windows-xp, printer, migration

I have old pc running with windows xp home edition in my office and we use it to print special papers with custom sizes. I would like to use newer computers with win 7. I can install drivers without problem but i can't transfer customised paper size forms from win xp. I seached internet but i coudn't find a way. Is there any way to transfer printer forms?
P.S. I tried to use Microsoft Print Migrator but somehow cab files getting curropted.

Comment: Why Windows 7? Remember that mainstream support for Windows 7 ended in January 2015.

Comment: it was already installed. If only I can export from windows xp, i believe i can use any OS